# enter key in input and double menu

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a menu and submenu program that produces a menu, then if you press 'p' you go to the submenu, and you should be able to exit the submenu by pressing 't' and then be able to exit the program by pressing 's'. The menu runs twice after pressing a button and i  assumed that was because cin.get() reads the enter key as an extra character, and i attempted to fix that by writing a function to filter out the enters from the users input, but the program still does not work as it is supposed to. Also i don't understand why the program does exit when the 's' key is pressed. Could someone please point out what i am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the code i have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void menu();

int main (){
    menu();
}//main

//regulating the input
void invoer (char in){
    cin.get(in);
    if (in=='\n'){
        cin.clear(in);
    }   //if
    cin.clear();
}   //invoer

void submenu(){
    bool submenu = true;
    while (submenu != false){
        cout<< "Dit is heb submenu, om uw parameters aan te passen: \n";
        cout<< "Maak hier uw keuze\n";
        cout<< "(T)erug,  \n";
        char s;
        invoer(s);
        switch (s)
        {
            case 'T':
            case 't':
                submenu = false;
                cin.clear();
                break;
            default:
                cout<< "Foutieve invoer, probeer het nog eens \n\n";
                break;
        } //switch
    }//while
}//submenu

void menu (){
    char m;
    bool menu = true;
    do
    {
        cout<< "Goedendag hiermee heeft u het menu om hiermee te oefenen: \n";
        cout<< "(S)toppen, s(C)hoon, (R)andom en (P)arameters \n" ;
        invoer(m);
        cout<<m;
        switch (m)
        {
            case 's':
                menu = false;
                break;
            case 'p':
                submenu();
                cin.clear();
                break;
            default :
                cout<< "Foutieve invoer, probeer het nog eens \n\n";
                break;
        }; // switch
    } // while
    while ( m != 'false');
} //menu
```

Comment: You're passing char to function invoer by value, so the actual input is not written to variable m in your do while loop. To fix that change definition of function to `void invoer (char& in)`.  Also, try to use debugger to figure out why your program does not work.

Comment: Probably you wanted `while ( menu != false);` instead of `while ( m != 'false');`